# Sums over residues with non-coprime moduli

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let $f$ be a $1$-periodic function (like $e^{2\pi ix}$). How can I evaluate a sum like $$\sum _{x=1}^{q}\sum _{y=1}^rf\left (\frac {x}{q}+\frac {y}{r}\right )$$ if $q,r$ are not coprime?

If they're coprime then the sum is $$\sum _{X=1}^{qr}f\left (\frac {X}{qr}\right )\sum _{x=1}^q\sum _{y=1\atop {xr+yq\equiv X(qr)}}^r1$$ and the congruence here is equivalent to $$X\equiv xr(q)\hspace {5mm}X\equiv yq(r)$$ which means there's only one choice for $x,y$ and the whole sum becomes $$\sum _{X=1}^{qr}f\left (\frac {X}{qr}\right ).$$

This is of course the Chinese Remainder Theorem and a version exists for non co-prime moduli in the form $$``X\equiv x(q)\hspace {5mm}X\equiv y(r)$$ have a unique solution mod $[q,r]$ provided $(q,r)|x-y$", but I can't make it work in the above case either.

Comment: Try isolating the greatest common divisor first

Comment: There are $qr$ summands, and $[q,r]$ possible values of the numerator when the denominator is fixed at $[q,r]$. What do you conjecture the distribution of the numerators will be among all summands? Try some small examples with specific numbers.

Comment: i see! thanks for the tip :)